# Why is a Spring singleton-scoped bean better than a classic Singleton pattern?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection, singleton

I do understand the difference between Spring singleton-scoped beans (they have a single instance for each Spring context) and the Singleton pattern (they have a single instance for the class loader).

I noticed that for many people the Singleton pattern is considered evil (because they are like global references), while nobody seems to have anything against the singleton-scoped beans (which are also globally available). Why is this?

I have a (desktop) app, where I need global access to some objects because it would be very cumbersome to pass references to dozens of classes and methods. However I don't want to use a DI framework because the startup time of the app is important. What is the best design?

Comment: *I don't want to use a DI framework because the startup time of the app is important* Have you measured the difference between both approaches? Is it very significant, I mean, probably 5 or 10 seconds really matter (and I'm just guessing because that's the time it takes when deploying a wide application that contains 200+ classes in a web application server)?

Comment: You're wrong about session-scoped beans. What you really mean is just Spring singletons. The session scope covers one session of a user with the Web server and doesn't even have a meaning in the context of a client-side desktop app.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think 5-10 seconds startup time do matter for a desktop app, which could be started multiple times by the users...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You are right, I meant singleton-scoped beans, I am editing the question

Comment: It will depend on the application type and what it will do. If it is a big app like Eclipse, of course it will take that time, but if its an app like a calculator, I'm sure adding spring to your app won't give the overhead you may think about. Do a basic test for it. If it is not worth it for your requirements, then don't use it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The app already has 1082 classes (actually class files counted with find . | grep class | wc -l), so it is not Eclipse, but not a calculator either, and it would take a considerable time to add spring to it just to see whether it ruined the startup time...

Comment: *it would take a considerable time to add spring to it just to see whether it ruined the startup time* that depends on your application design, but by this comment seems to be something hard...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`public static`-flavored singletons are in disfavor because they are hardwired into a class, not because they are global. People will tell you they are impossible to mock for testing, for example. If you only have a handful of global objects, you don't need Spring just to avoid such plain Java singletons. However, if you have a substantial object graph which needs to be wired together, then your code will come off much cleaner if you use the DI approach.

There are a lot of conveniences in Spring to manage the bean lifecycle and it is especially convenient that you can change the lifecycle fairly easily, for example from singleton to prototype. Such a requirement may arise due to a late decision to execute parts of code concurrently, and the code relies on non-threadsafe objects.

Comment: I have 3-4 Singletons now, and unit testing them would be very hard anyway, because there is little "business logic" around them, they are GUI-related classes, for example I need the main JFrame reference (as a parent) everywhere a dialog might pop up. So you are saying that I should keep using the singletons?

Comment: Ask yourself whether you feel there's anything wrong with the static singletons you have: are they giving you any sort of trouble? If not, then don't let any blanket "best practices" intimidate you :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that [session-scoped beans are only relevant in a `WebApplicationContext`.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other)

Spring (or any other IoC container) is responsible for creating these beans and all your application has to worry about is requesting them. That's why using DI managed singletons is so much better/easier.

Comment: Well implementing the Singleton pattern is very easy, and also accessing these objects. I don't see why is it better if the DI framework manages my singletons.

Comment: @user1954847 With a container you don't have to implement the pattern, you just have to request the instance.

Comment: It takes me only a short time to implement a singleton pattern, and actually it is already implemented, I just wonder whether there is a better design which preserves the startup time.

Comment: @user1954847 Startup up time can be reduced by lazy initializing your instances. A DI container provides that out of the box as well.

Comment: I don't think lazy initialization would save me much, because I need to initialize most objects anyway at startup.

Comment: @user1954847 Let's get to the answer you are apparently looking for. `Why is a Spring singleton-scoped bean better than a classic Singleton pattern?` It is only better when you require some or all of its additional features. I think your best bet is to research these features (see my link) and find out if they fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**With public static style singleton:**
1. Unit testing is difficult.  Think of injecting a mock dependency with a constructor, it's simply not possible!
2. Difficult to perform clean-up operations on or before object destroy.  Objects lives till the end of application.

**With Sprint Singleton style pattern:**
1. Bean can be created by using new keyword,  constructor injection can be done easily.
2. Unit testing with mock object is possible due to constructor injection.
3. Full control over Life cycle of the Singleton bean is possible, for example Post-Construct ( do something after object creation) and Pre-Destroy ( do something before object's destroy )
4. Singleton bean can be changed to non-singleton bean, for example to Prototype, very easily.

Comment: Oh, it is very much possible to mock singletons: https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/07/01/TheLittleSingleton.html